# Respone vs ServletResponse vs HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, java-ee

Всем привет.

При написании проекта появился вопрос по теме над который я не особо задумывался.

А в чём собственно разница между Response , ServletResponse , HttpServletResponse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpServletResponse

> Extends the ServletResponse interface to provide HTTP-specific
>   functionality in sending a response. For example, it has methods to
>   access HTTP headers and cookies.

Предполагается, что технология servlet-ов не привязана к одному лишь http. Хотя о других "привязках" широким массам неизвестно, даже если они и существуют.

Поэтому ServletResponse - это некоторый абстрактный ответ какого-то абстрактного Servlet-а.
А HttpServletResponse - это конкретный такой ServletResponse конкретного HttpServlet-а.

Что за Response в эту компанию записали совершенно не понятно. Поэтому будем считать, что это слово означает точно то, что и означает - какой-либо ответ/отклик (чего(кого)-либо на что-либо).
Применительно к сервлетам по мере уточнения классов действующих сущностей превращается сначала в ServletResponse, а потом в HttpServletResponse.

Comment: Так вот что значит превращается ? 
При создании респонса "Response" и возврате допустим в каком либо методе, этот респонс и информация в нём доходит до браузера(клиента) ? Как там проходит это превращение ?

Comment: @Maks.Burkov Я же вроде чётко дал понять, что не понимаю о каком Response идёт речь. Не знаю никакого Response в херархии респонсов сервлета. Поэтому всё, что касается Вашего Response - это шутка с долей истины. Респонсы используются по всюду, где их только нет. Поэтому пока не ясно о каком именно речь - ничего конкретного сказать не возможно.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html
Да ладно всё понятно.. Вот из документации посмотри. Главное без нервов!

Comment: Этот Response из RESTful API совершенно отличный от ServletResponse из Servlet API.

Comment: REST обычно функционирует в качестве Servlet-а. Но программисту предоставляется совершенно другой API. На основе построенного Вами Response REST-фреймвёрк сам заполняет HttpServletResponse как считает нужным.

Comment: Тем не менее есть возможность использовать HttpServletResponse и в методе REST-сервиса, передав ему параметр `@Context HttpServletResponse response`. Тогда, если например закрыть выходной поток `response.getOutputStream().close()` (на самом достаточно добится, чтобы хотя бы заголовки ушли клиенту) , то REST-фреймвёрку ничего другого как согласиться с этим не останется. А построенный мимоходом Response будет просто проигнорирован. Очень удобно таким образом делать поточную раздачу из REST-сервиса длинных файлов например

Comment: Сергей у вас есть ссылка на объяснение этого механизма работы из какой либо книги ? Или блога ? а то я абсолютно нечего не понял..

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ Но не смотря на "официальность" довольно скудное описание. У каждой технологии, входящей в набор javaee есть документ с полным описанием спецификации. Но это уже не руководство. Изучать так трудно, то практически не возможно.

Comment: Про сервлеты можно найти неплохие описания даже на русском. Это базовая технология  всего, что связано с web, http в серверах на java. Всё остальное - надстройки над сервлетами, некоторые из которых хорошо их прячут. RESTFUL глубоко не изучал. Так пару методов всего. Может на http://resteasy.jboss.org/ или https://jersey.java.net/ пошукать. REST довольно маленький, учить там нечего. Прибегаешь к какм-то поискам только при конкретных затруднениях